# react-paypal-js not always loading inside component and how to show error on paypal-button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

I've 2 Problems with my react-paypal-js payment gateway.
I'm using PayPal on three parts of my site.
One is a single payment button that works fine (Without Merchant ID).
And then there are 2 buttons in one component (With Merchant ID).
One if you order as guest and one for a registered user.

I've sometimes this problem: "window.paypal.Buttons is undefined"
It's kinda fixable by adding another PayPalScriptProvider in my App.js
The problem is, that it uses merchant ID and let's say the single payment button would have same problem and uses the PayPalScriptProvider from App.js then the money goes to wrong person.

So my first problem is: How can I use react-paypal-js reliable inside my Cart component

And the second problem is: How can I show a Toast Error when e.g. Terms of Service not accepted onClick on the PayPal button + not opening the PayPal window. So when there is error only show error, and when there is no error open the PayPal window.

```
const initialOptions = {
  'client-id': 'test',
  // 'merchant-id': 'test',
  currency: 'EUR',
  intent: 'capture',
  'enable-funding': ['sofort', 'giropay'],
  'disable-funding': ['card', 'sepa'],
};

function App() {
  return (
    <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Pages />
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Cart component:
It has initialOptions and checks some stuff like: Terms of Service accepted? Min amount? and so on.

```
const initialOptions = {
  'client-id': 'test',
  // 'merchant-id': 'test',
  // components: 'buttons',
  currency: 'EUR',
  intent: 'capture',
  'enable-funding': ['sofort', 'giropay'],
  'disable-funding': ['card', 'sepa'],
};

const CartScreen = () => {
  const [paypalErros, setPaypalError] = useState(true);

...

  const paypalTranSuccess = async (payment) => {
    const { paymentID } = payment;
    if (sliderDeliveryValue === '') {
      toast.error(`Choose delivery method`, {
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      });
      setPaypalError(true);
      return false;
    }
      if (!acceptBox) {
        toast.error(`Accept ToS`, {
          position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        });
        setLoading(false);
        setPaypalError(true);
        return false;
      }
      setPaypalError(false);
    } else {
      setPaypalError(true);
      setLoading(false);
      toast.error(`Mindestbestellwert 2.00€`, {
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      });
    }
  };

<div onClick={paypalTranSuccess}>
   <PayPalButton
     carttotal={carttotal}
     paypalErros={paypalErros}
     paypalTranSuccess={paypalTranSuccess,}
   />
</div>
```

My PayPalButton component

```
const PayPalFeeButton = ({
  carttotal,
  paypalErros,
  paypalTranSuccess,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [{ isPending }] = usePayPalScriptReducer();
  return (
    <>
      {isPending ? <LoadingMedium /> : null}
      <PayPalButtons
        onClick={(data, actions) => {
          paypalTranSuccess();

          if (!paypalErros) {
            alert("TEST);
            return actions.reject();
          } else {
            return actions.resolve();
          }
        }}
        createOrder={(data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                description: 'Order',
                amount: {
                  value: carttotal,
                  currency_code: 'EUR',
                },
              },
            ]
          });
        }}
        onError={() => {
          //setPaid(false);
          toast.error('Zahlung nicht erfolgreich', {
             position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
          });
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Edit Errors:

```
react-paypal-js.js:417 Uncaught Error: Unable to render <PayPalButtons /> because window.paypal.Buttons is undefined.
To fix the issue, add 'buttons' to the list of components passed to the parent PayPalScriptProvider:
`<PayPalScriptProvider options={{ components: 'buttons'}}>`.

The above error occurred in the <PayPalButtons> component:

react-paypal-js.js:417 Uncaught Error: Unable to render <PayPalButtons /> because window.paypal.Buttons is undefined.
To fix the issue, add 'buttons' to the list of components passed to the parent PayPalScriptProvider:
`<PayPalScriptProvider options={{ components: 'buttons'}}>`.
```

Edit Errors 2:

```
I added the components: 'buttons'

Uncaught Error: Attempted to load sdk version 5.0.338 on page, but window.paypal at version undefined already loaded.

To load this sdk alongside the existing version, please specify a different namespace in the script tag, e.g. <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT_ID" data-namespace="paypal_sdk"></script>, then use the paypal_sdk namespace in place of paypal in your code.


Uncaught Error: Attempted to load sdk version 5.0.338 on page, but window.paypal at version undefined already loaded.

Uncaught Error: Unable to render <PayPalButtons /> because window.paypal.Buttons is undefined.

The above error occurred in the <PayPalButtons> component:

Uncaught Error: Unable to render <PayPalButtons /> because window.paypal.Buttons is undefined.
```

Comment: This solution resolved my issue as the PayPal button is now always visible. However, I'm curious why it is correct to use <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}> within the App functional component instead of a child component.

When I tried using <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}> within a child functional component, I encountered rendering issues. For example, it would work the first time, but after a navigation redirect, it wouldn't render. This behavior seems quite unusual.

Answer (score 0):

"window.paypal.Buttons is undefined" means the JS SDK failed to load for some reason. See what details you can find about the failure in browser console and network tab

As far as I know the the SDK merchant-id is used for button eligibility decisions but you still need to [specify a `payee` object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/) in order creation if you want the receiver to be an account other than the APP client-id account.

Comment: I edit 2 errors. First i fixed but about the second one i don't know. And for the onClick I kinda found a solution. I edit the onClick and it shows error. But there is still a PayPal window opening, but it crashes / not loading and then shows my onError. Is there a way this window is not opening / close by itself?

Comment: You can disable the buttons from an onInit function and only re-enable them when appropriate. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/validate-user-input/